# Is there any way i can get access to temporally folder on Amazon wwwroot folder when in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am importing excel files to the folder i created in the wwwroot directory on Amazon. But My application is denied access to the folder so that i can upload in it the file and then access the file

```
                var folder = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles");
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folder);
                FileSystemAccessRule fsar = new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
                DirectorySecurity ds = null;
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                }
                ds = di.GetAccessControl();
                ds.AddAccessRule(fsar);

                string path = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles/" + UploadedFile.FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                UploadedFile.SaveAs(path);
                //Read from excel file
                Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

I expect the ExcelFiles folder to be created in case it does not exist and then the file is uploaded in the folder. after it has been uploaded then i get the content from the uploaded file. But now when i import the file this is the error i get.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ExcelFiles\Recep.xlsx' is denied. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ExcelFiles\Recep.xlsx' is denied. ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access. Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. Stack Trace: [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ExcelFiles\Recep.xlsx' is denied.] System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +417 System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1217 System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +130 System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +97 System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +99 Nmicros.Accounts.Web.Controllers.ReceiptController.Import(HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile) in D:\Rogers\Projects\NMS\nmicros.accounts\Nmicros.Accounts.Web\Controllers\ReceiptController.cs:181 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +72 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +387 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +42 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +648 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

Comment: Even if you could do this, you wouldn't be able to do Excel automation on AWS. That requires Excel to be installed on the server, which is a really bad idea even when you control the hardware.